# Spring JDBC Template database dialects

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc, design-patterns

What is the right way for working with different databases (Oracle, MSSql, MySql) via Spring JDBC Template ? I need implement specific db queries for paging. Need i use something as:

```
if (Oracle){
   opacle specific query
}
if (MSSql){
   MSSql specific query
}
```

Or there is better way for this ?

Comment: Unfortuntely, this is as good as it gets. `JDBCTemplate` is not modifying your SQL in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DAO pattern is the typical way of dealing with that. Specify a DAO interface, provide multiple implementations of this DAO interface (one per database, but sharing common code through inheritance, for example), and inject an instance of the appropriate implementation (based on the Spring configuration) into your service class.

Spring-JDBC will be of no help here: it simply executes the SQL queries you ask it to execute.

Comment: never thought like this way, brilliant. do you know any open source projects implementing this approach?